# How to get count of individuals within group_concat without always defaulting to 1

Tags: sql, sqlite

I built a table that looks like this:

| UID | city | type | pets | pet_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | paris | house |  | 1 |
| 2 | paris | condo | cat | 1 |
| 3 | london | townhouse | dog, bird | 2 |
| 4 | london | tree house | hawk, fish, hamster | 3 |
| 5 | london | caravan | elephant | 1 |
| 6 | london | boat |  | 1 |

I got this table from the following query:

```
SELECT uid, city, type, group_concat(o.animals) as pets, count(*) as pet_count
```

My goal was to build a table that listed each unique type of house with its city, and then concatenated its pets into a single field, and then counted those pets.

This is what I am expecting

| UID | city | type | pets | pet_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | paris | house |  | 0 |
| 2 | paris | condo | cat | 1 |
| 3 | london | townhouse | dog, bird | 2 |
| 4 | london | tree house | hawk, fish, hamster | 3 |
| 5 | london | caravan | elephant | 1 |
| 6 | london | boat |  |  |

The problem I'm having is that the count always returns a 1, even when there are no owners counted.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try count(o.animals) rather than count(*). Count(*) will just count the rows whereas if you count a specific column it will count the non-null values in that column

Comment: your result may look this way but not your  table, please post a [mre] with the correct data

Comment: Your code does not have a `from` clause (not to mention the missing `group by` clause as well), which makes your question rather unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sum()` combined with `case` clause as follows :

```
SELECT UID, city, type, group_concat(o.animals) as pets, 
            sum(case when o.animals is not null then 1 else 0 end) as pet_count
...
```

The condition can also be `o.animals <> ''`  depending on whether you have null or empty values.